# Analytic continuation for Harmonic series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, reference-request, summation, harmonic-numbers

It is known that $$H_x=\sum_{n=1}^x\frac1n$$Which is very well known because of its interesting behavior as $x\rightarrow\infty$. Now this sum is defined only for positive integers $x$ because it is at the top of the summand. However, in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652897/how-to-show-that-fracddx-sum-n-1-infty-left-frac-xn-ln-left1-frac-x) I found a telescoping series that becomes the Harmonic series. It looks like this: $$H_x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac x{n(n+x)}$$ This sum is defined for all numbers except the negative integers (like the Gamma function apparently...). This sum has been written before on stackexchange (I don't have the link right now), but usually this integral is preferred: $$H_x=\int_0^1\frac{t^x-1}{t-1}dt$$ Which is defined only for positive $x$. Is there any reason why this integral is preferred over the sum?

Comment: For an even more general form note that $H_z=z{_3F_2}\left({1,1,1-z\atop 2,2};1\right)$

Comment: @AaronHendrickson What is $_3F_2$?

Comment: Generalized hypergeometric series ${_3F_2}\left({a_1,a_2,a_3\atop b_1,b_2};z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a_1)_n(a_2)_n(a_3)_n}{(b_1)_n(b_2)_n}\frac{z^n}{n!}$

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Okay, that clears things up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it is easier to compute asymptotics for an integral than for a sum. For example, Stirling formula can be deduced from the integral form given by the Gamma function by using the [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).

Another somewhat more elementary example of the relationship between series and integrals is given by comparing a series with an integral in order to assert its convergence.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The sum and integral are equivalent.

Note

$$\frac{1}{t-1}=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty t^{\,n-1},\quad -1<t<1\tag{1}$$

so

$$\int\limits_0^1 \frac{t^x-1}{t-1}\,dt=-\int\limits_0^1 \left(t^x-1\right)\, \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty t^{\,n-1}\,dt=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \int_\limits0^1 \left(t^x-1\right)\, t^{\,n-1}\,dt=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n\, (n+x)}\tag{2}$$

which is valid for $\Re(x)>-1$.

Comment: The problem is that last statement, "...which is valid for $\Re(x)>-1$. When $\Re(x)<-1$ the RHS is still defined for all non-integer negative numbers. But the LHS isn't.

Comment: @KamalSaleh Actually the series is globally convergent except at negative integers where the Harmonic number function exhibits a complex infinity, so there is no inconsistency.

Comment: I mean that the integral doesn't extend to the negative numbers like the series.

Comment: @KamalSaleh I see what you mean now. The term-wise integral doesn't extend to negative numbers like the series either, but I've found that convergence of a series derived from term-wise integration is not necessarily related to convergence of the term-wise integral.

Comment: @KamalSaleh Another example is for $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \theta (x-n)$, the term wise integral $s \int\limits_0^\infty \theta (x-n)\, x^{-s-1}\,dx=n^{-s}$ is valid for $\Re(s)>0$, but the series $\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ is only valid for $\Re(s)>1$. So a series derived from term-wise integration may converge over a smaller or greater range than its related term-wise integral.

Comment: What is $\theta(x)$? Is it Heaviside Step function?

Comment: @KamalSaleh Yes, $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \theta(x-n)$ is equivalent to $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x 1$ except possibly $\theta(x-n)$ may be undefined when $x=n$ depending on the convention.